# Keep screen on when application is running

Tags: screen, phonegap

I am working on PhoneGap application. I want the screen to be shown when my application is in the foreground. But screen goes to lock due to inactivity.

I tried using `flag_screen_on` in mainactivity file. It's not working. I tried using wakelock too. It didn't work too.

Can you please suggest any other ways to keep the screen on when the application is opened. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, There is a [plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin) created by the **EddyVerbruggen**. You can include this within your project. Documentation is pretty simple for same.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. The flag_screen_on is working in Android 7.0 but not in Android 7.1.. Is this a version issue? The plugin was not working in my case.

Comment: would recommend you to open an issue on github repository.

Comment: This plugin dont work anymore in largets Android versions

Answer (score 0):

Added these lines of code in MainActivity.java. Here is the code snippet

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: what do you think about https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/master/src/android/nl/xservices/plugins/Insomnia.java